# What is this plant with a thick woody stem and waxy leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

I found this plant in the recycling room in my building and its taken quite well to its new home. But what is it?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the rubber plant, [Ficus elastica](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ficus_elastica).  It has white sticky sap and can grow into a tree (100 - 200 feet 30 - 60 M) tall when grown outdoors in the tropics.

This plant will tolerate shade, neglect and more.  A nice appearance and good health is maintained with

- diffuse high light
- regular watering
- fertilize lightly once a year
- repot yearly if you want a big plant
- do not be afraid to cut back hard if it looks leggy. This plant will bud slowly from old wood
- pests are infrequent due to the hard waxy coating but mealybug and scale can occur.  Soap and water applications at 5 ml/l will control the problem.

Comment: Now we just need a metal tree and we never have to buy tires again!!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a rubber tree to me. If you break a leaf off, is it sticky milky ooze?

Comment: Yes the latex does ooze out.